# How to test my application on a windows mobile standard sdk?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I made my application in the windows professional sdk. Now I would like to see how my application looks in none touch screen applications.

How do I change my emulator to run a standard mobile phone? I have both professional and standard installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the project and select "Change Target Platform"

Answer (score 0):

Hey.. Change the target platform...
cradle the respective emulator and Deploy ... it will work...

Answer (score 0):

```
>>tools
>>connect to a device
_choose the emulator you need_
>>connect
>>F5
```

maybe the description of the menu can be slightly different because i have the italian version of VS.